# python / django, where is the root of the namespace?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

coming from php, the namespaces are always well defined in php, typically using psr-4 from composer

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4

e.g. you have a folder

`src/Foo/Bar/Baz`

you then define in the `composer.json` file that
`src/Foo` is where the namespace `Foo` starts

thereafter, all subfolders are by convention, a new sub namespace e.g.

`src/Foo/Bar/Baz/MyClass.php` turns into

`Foo.Bar.Baz.MyClass`

Say I want to drop a utility python class into my django project, that I want to use in all django "apps"

Where would I drop it, and how to properly define the namespace? what is the transparent way to understand namespaces in python?

Comment: Thanks for that link to psr-4, I suspect that will be useful for me later.

Comment: @davejagoda none the less, the psr 4 doc is confusing (I had my time to get started with it) thus I created a little gist for you, of a real life composer.json here. Notice: I don't end the folder with a `/` unlike in the docs. Was that a pitfall? I cannot remember, but it might help you, so there it is https://gist.github.com/Jossnaz/f920231e5018907691621b62a61b0a39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, there is a search path for modules. It can be initialized from the command line with the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and accessed programmatically via [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html).

By default, the directory of the script you use to start the Python interpreter is the first entry in the search path.

Any module or package on the python path "starts a new namespace", to use your wording. Let's assume your project called `mysite` has an app called `polls` and has this structure:

```
mysite
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── polls
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── utils.py
...
```

If you start it with `python manage.py runserver`, the packages `mysite` and `polls` are available.

I'd say a good place for project-wide utils module is the project package `mysite`. So you do `import mysite.utils` in any of your apps. If it grows beyond a single file, you can turn it into a subpackage, so instead of a `utils.py`, you have a `utils` directory containing an `__init__.py` file.

The above structure clutters the global namespace a bit. So some people prefer a structure where all your apps are subpackages of your project package, like this:

```
mysite
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── apps
│       └── polls
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── models.py
│           ├── utils.py
...
```

Answer (score 3):

From this document:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#projects-and-applications

Is this snippet:

`A project’s root directory (the one that contains manage.py) is usually the container for all of a project’s applications which aren’t installed separately.`

You can create whatever hierarchy you chose under that directory for utilities, which can conform to python's `package` system:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages